# How to extract a row by an approximate value in a column?

Tags: r

How can you extract a row using an approximate value in a column, such as 5? I want to extract the row with the data value closest to 5 in a certain column.
[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPkSw.png)

For example, I want to extract the row with the data value closest to 5 in `pro.f column`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of the number closest to 5 in the pro.f column using `abs()` along with `which.min()`. Then, use that as an index to extract that particular row.

```
df[which.min(abs(df$pro.f - 5)),]
```

Output

```
  var freq pro.f
3 328   12  5.09
```

Data

```
structure(list(
  var = c(326, 327, 328),
  freq = c(10, 11, 12),
  pro.f = c(4.24, 4.65, 5.09)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`you can use `slice_min`:

```
df %>%
  slice_min(abs(pro.f - 5))
  var freq pro.f pro.f_temp
1 328   12  5.09       0.09
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var = c(326, 327, 328, 322, 321),
  freq = c(10, 11, 12, 10, 11),
  pro.f = c(4.24, 4.65, 5.09, 5.10, 5.11)
)
```